# Build swagger dynamically In .Net Core

Tags: c#, swagger-ui

I have a list of APIs and when one of the APIs is selected, I want to display the Swagger page for that API only.

[image]

In the Program.cs file

```
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger(options =>
    
        {
        });
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
    
        });
    }
```

[and there is a link to the project here.](https://github.com/SoheilaHashemi/Swagger/)

Comment: So you just want to alter the appearance/interactivity of the Swagger documentation page? Because your question's title suggests you want to build a Swagger _service definition_ at runtime, which isn't what you're describing.

Comment: The mentioned code in Program.cs will be executed once at startup and not at runtime.

Comment: Is there a way to make swagger at runtime?